# A little transparency, better reading experience?

Tags: css, text, colors, transparency, rgba

Recently, I noticed the color setting from my friend's blog. The blog has white background and a text color setting `rbga(51, 51, 51, .85)`, and it's used to overwrite `#333`, which is before the applied one.

I guessed the latter one is a trick for IE which not supported for transparency. But the problem is, is there any benefit to do with the *rbga with a little transparency* for *reading text*?

P.S. `#333` is equal to `rbga(51, 51, 51, 1)`, not `rgba(51, 51, 51, .85)` below.

[image: color code applied changed #333 to rgba(51, 51, 51, .85)]

(see the `color` setting)

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't make complete sense. The screenshot you attached shows that the CSS goes from hex => rgba. They likely did this so as to be able to make the text somewhat transparent, as noted by the .85 value in the alpha value.

As you noted, they may have kept the hexadecimal value in case the site is run through a browser which does not support rgba.

Comment: Yep, my question is why make text a little transparent?

Comment: That is for the developer to answer. Text transparency can be a desired effect depending on what her/his intentions are. One instance of desiring semi-transparent text is when I am doing command-line work. Often times I have a stack overflow post behind my terminal, so I make the text and background semi-transparent so I can see the post behind it.